# start batchscript on remote host over ssh

Tags: batch-file, ssh, cygwin, windows-10, openssh

i have this setup:

1 Host with Windows 10 and Cygwin Unix Tools (for a unix filesystem and the open-ssh server).
2 On the Other side there is another Linux Gentoo client.
Is there any chance to execute batch file on the host?
Like this 'ssh name@host start data.bat'?

U guys would help me a lot <3

Answer (score 0):

If we you want to run command/script on the Windows 10 host, you need a SSH server set up on Windows. Although there are some rumors that Windows Powershell will have built-in SSH server support, I did not aware that it is released yet.

That being said, you have any third party tools to set it up . For example, check [here](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2016/04/using-ssh-with-powershell/).

Comment: thats the wrong direction. To execute bash scripts from an cygwin environment to a linux machine isnt the problem. I will execute '.bat' batch script from a linux gentoo machine over ssh